# C/C++ memory-allocation boundary-alignment for Android

Tags: android, c++, memory-alignment

Is there a preferred C/C++ technique for forcing (say) 32-byte alignment for Android?

I'm currently using:

```
// require N * sizeof(float) to be multiple of 32
float* w  __attribute__((aligned(32)));
int ret = posix_memalign((void**)&w, 32, N * sizeof(float));
```

Is it necessary to provide `__attribute__`?

Is this the best method?

Comment: What do you mean with "the best method"?

Comment: You should only need `float* w` with `posix_memalign` unless you are using `w` in an unusual way. `float* w  __attribute__((aligned(32)));` aligns the pointer itself instead of the pointed-to data. Usually the pointed-to data is what is important. And as far as I know, you will only need the pointed-to data to be 32-byte aligned for AVX2 and BMI2 (and friends).

Comment: @jww If you would care to move the comment to an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!